# How do I make this smooth string-like saw lead?

Tags: synthesizer, techniques, replication, electronic-music

There's a very specific smooth, string instrument-esque lead that's been used a lot in songs made by producers in a small electronic niche.  It originated with the band *Point Point*, and since they first used it it's been used countless times in songs by artists connected to their record label, *Record Record*, so either Point Point gave their label artists this sound to use, or it's easy enough to replicate that everyone in the niche uses it.  Its almost definitely a saw wave, but I cannot figure out the rest for the life of me.  I put unison, legato, and portamento on it, but it ended up just sounding like a high-pitched hardstyle lead.  In this particular lead, all the voices sound so smooth like a violin, but my lead sounds rough and gritty, like [this](https://youtu.be/jCQGFjJhnxo?t=126) (but a saw wave, not a square).  Any ideas?

These are some examples:

https://soundcloud.com/asangotbeats/when-u-let-go (At 1:09)

There are countless more examples that I don't remember at this moment, but those are all the same lead.

Comment: "*those are all the same lead*"  They are ? What is the similarity of the three examples ?  They all seem very different.

Comment: @AlaskaMan a) they all have the same characteristics in different octaves and when changing pitch, and if you listen to them closely you will hear that they are the exact same sound.  the only difference was octave in which they were played in and the accompanying instruments.  b) music made with synthesis is real music just as much as any other genre is and there is no way to dispute that without making the same arguments for almost any other music at all.  btw there were four examples, and now five.

Comment: In [this demo](https://youtu.be/3iZzTiKHojE) many of the vintage synths are named that had similar sound presets, but no detail is given to how to build up a "strings" synth from nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still relevant I think what you should investigate are so called "superwaves". Those synths use a large numer of oscillators to generate sound, with spectra well beyond traditional pulse, saw, triangle, rect etc.

In a nutshell, you could do Fourier-synthesis, i.e. combine as many oscillator frequencies and volumes as you need. Here are some spectra of classical instruments for reference, which you can try to match or mismatch, as in your audio examples:

[image: classical instruments spectra]

There are many hardware and (cheaper, sometimes free) software solutions implementing superwave concepts. Search e.g. on this [youtube-rival](https://vid.puffyan.us/search?q=superwave%20synth). E.g. [here](https://vid.puffyan.us/watch?v=F-iY8Kes04w) at about 05:18 there is some string like sound.

Find a basic sound, which has most of what you'd like to hear. Work from there to apply parameter variations as needed, like filters, filter modulation, ADSR and so on.

It's possible to approach the string like sound you want somewhat with classical synth waveforms (as mentioned above). But it will probably be less in sound quality.